# Parse large xml file in R

Tags: r, xml

I've been struggling with loading/parsing my xml file in R. I've tried both the XML and the xml2 package with no luck. The file size is 275,000kb. I've been able to load other xml files and parse the data however I can't seem to figure this out.

Below is a sample of the xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<T_WC>
  <xs:schema id="T_WC" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="T_WC" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="api_st_cde" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="api_cnty_cde" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="api_well_idn" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="pool_idn" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="eff_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ogrid_cde" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="well_typ_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sdiv_twp_idn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sdiv_rng_idn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sdiv_sect_num" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sdiv_unlt_idn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="lot_idn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ftg_ns_num" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ftg_ew_num" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ns_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ew_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="compl_typ_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="compl_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="dpth_perf_top_num" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="dpth_perf_btm_num" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="fst_oil_prodn_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="fst_gas_deliv_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tst_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="prodn_meth_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tst_len_tim" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tbg_pres_num" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="csg_pres_num" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="choke_siz_dec" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tst_oil_amt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tst_wtr_amt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tst_gas_amt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="api_grav_dec" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tst_meth_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tst_gor_dec" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="wc_stat_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tst_gas_dispn_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="spc_unit_idn" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="prod_prop_idn" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="well_nbr_idn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="vent_apr_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="vent_apr_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="vent_apr_expr_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ocd_lease_num" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="well_class_cde" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="well_grp_num" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="bh_psd_act_ind" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sdiv_consol_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="dhc_cmngl_ind" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ocd_ord_typ_cde" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ocd_ord_num" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ocd_ord_sfx_idn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="dhc_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="nfo_prmt_num" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="nfo_eff_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="nfo_expr_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="deliv_tst_q_num" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="c104_apr_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="gas_conn_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ocd_unlt_idn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="rec_termn_dte" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Table>
    <api_st_cde>30</api_st_cde>
    <api_cnty_cde>1</api_cnty_cde>
    <api_well_idn>5002</api_well_idn>
    <pool_idn>96838</pool_idn>
    <eff_dte>1964-04-24T00:00:00-06:00</eff_dte>
    <ogrid_cde>196291</ogrid_cde>
    <well_typ_cde>G</well_typ_cde>
    <sdiv_twp_idn>10N</sdiv_twp_idn>
    <sdiv_rng_idn>05E</sdiv_rng_idn>
    <sdiv_sect_num>12</sdiv_sect_num>
    <sdiv_unlt_idn>D  </sdiv_unlt_idn>
    <lot_idn xml:space="preserve">      </lot_idn>
    <ftg_ns_num>985</ftg_ns_num>
    <ftg_ew_num>902</ftg_ew_num>
    <ns_cde>N</ns_cde>
    <ew_cde>W</ew_cde>
    <compl_typ_cde xml:space="preserve"> </compl_typ_cde>
    <compl_dte>9999-12-31T00:00:00-07:00</compl_dte>
    <dpth_perf_top_num>1</dpth_perf_top_num>
    <dpth_perf_btm_num>1</dpth_perf_btm_num>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <api_st_cde>30</api_st_cde>
    <api_cnty_cde>1</api_cnty_cde>
    <api_well_idn>20007</api_well_idn>
    <pool_idn>96838</pool_idn>
    <eff_dte>1997-09-29T00:00:00-06:00</eff_dte>
    <ogrid_cde>14538</ogrid_cde>
    <well_typ_cde>G</well_typ_cde>
    <sdiv_twp_idn>10N</sdiv_twp_idn>
    <sdiv_rng_idn>01E</sdiv_rng_idn>
    <sdiv_sect_num>21</sdiv_sect_num>
    <sdiv_unlt_idn>G50</sdiv_unlt_idn>
    <lot_idn xml:space="preserve">      </lot_idn>
    <ftg_ns_num>640</ftg_ns_num>
    <ftg_ew_num>590</ftg_ew_num>
    <ns_cde>S</ns_cde>
    <ew_cde>W</ew_cde>
    <compl_typ_cde xml:space="preserve"> </compl_typ_cde>
    <compl_dte>9999-12-31T00:00:00-07:00</compl_dte>
    <dpth_perf_top_num>1</dpth_perf_top_num>
    <dpth_perf_btm_num>1</dpth_perf_btm_num>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <api_st_cde>30</api_st_cde>
    <api_cnty_cde>1</api_cnty_cde>
    <api_well_idn>20010</api_well_idn>
    <pool_idn>96838</pool_idn>
    <eff_dte>2015-06-02T00:00:00-06:00</eff_dte>
    <ogrid_cde>5380</ogrid_cde>
    <well_typ_cde>G</well_typ_cde>
    <sdiv_twp_idn>10N</sdiv_twp_idn>
    <sdiv_rng_idn>01W</sdiv_rng_idn>
    <sdiv_sect_num>27</sdiv_sect_num>
    <sdiv_unlt_idn>G50</sdiv_unlt_idn>
    <lot_idn xml:space="preserve">      </lot_idn>
    <ftg_ns_num>800</ftg_ns_num>
    <ftg_ew_num>800</ftg_ew_num>
    <ns_cde>S</ns_cde>
    <ew_cde>E</ew_cde>
    <compl_typ_cde xml:space="preserve"> </compl_typ_cde>
    <compl_dte>9999-12-31T00:00:00-07:00</compl_dte>
    <dpth_perf_top_num>1</dpth_perf_top_num>
    <dpth_perf_btm_num>1</dpth_perf_btm_num>
   </Table>
```

Comment: What does "with no luck" mean? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it appears the problem was with the code at the end. I downloaded the file again and it is working properly. I'm currently using the xmlToDataFrame() function although it's taking a long time to run.

Comment: What code at end? We only see an XML file.

Comment: I misspoke, I meant to say at the end of the XML file.